# How to edit this matrix R?

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix named dx:

```
     a b c d e f g h

cat  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 

dog  1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1

fish 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 

egg  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

How do I delete the rows that goes all zero across like cat and egg. So that I can end up with this only -

```
     a b c d e f g h

dog  1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1

fish 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: assuming nothing other than 0 or 1: `dx[rowSums(dx) != 0, ]`

Comment: @jeremycg - works here (like you said only works if your only values are 0's and 1's), but Frank's comment below shows how this could fail if you had other values (probably relevant for OP)

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
m<-matrix(c(1,1,1,0,
        0,0,0,0,
        1,0,1,0,
        0,0,0,0,
        1,1,1,1),ncol=4,byrow=T)
m[rowSums(abs(m))!=0,]
```

Comment: Np, here is a goofy variant: `m[ !!rowSums(!!m), ]` that works because `x != 0` works the same as `!!x`

Answer (score 0):

```
zeros_removed = apply(dx, 1, function(row) all(row !=0 ))
dx[zeros_removed,]
```

Comment: @MichaelChirico - Thanks. Rookie mistake to forget to format my answer as code.

Comment: No problem. For reference, the other solution is much faster because `rowSums` is optimized. `apply`, on the other hand, is good to know for more general row-wise situations (when we can't use `sum`).